# Why Tailwind CSS is not working when applying on an active link?

Tags: vuejs3, tailwind-css, inertiajs

I'm using Tailwind CSS, Vue JS, and Inertia for my practice project. I'm trying to add some other classes when the specific link is visited. But the problem is updated class is not working.

I have tried the below code.

```
 <Link :href="route('profile.index')" 
  class="link-btn" 
  :class="{'link-btn-active' :route('profile.index')}">
  Profiles
  </Link>
```

This is what I have written in Tailwind CSS

```
.link-btn{
  @apply  pl-[5px] bg-red-500 opacity-60;
  }
 .link-btn-active{
  @apply  pl-[10px] bg-green-500 opacity-100;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this :

```html
<template>
  <Link :href="route('profile.index')" 
    class="link-btn" 
    :class="{'link-btn-active' : isActive('profile.index')}">
    Profiles
  </Link>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  computed: {
    isActive(routeName) {
      return this.$route.name === routeName
    }
  }
}
</script>
```